# Query select on varchar2 works without apex

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a query on field type `varchar2` that works also without apex.
E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = 123456
```

where `field` is `varchar2`, and it returns the result and not the

> ORA-01722: invalid number.

There is some setting on DB that make it possible? Thankx.

Answer (score 1):

If that column's datatype is `varchar2`, then enclose its value with single quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field = '123456'
```

There's no setting that would "remove" invalid number error, as far as I can tell.

---

Query you posted works when there are only "numbers" in a table; though, when "something else" (it is a `varchar2` after all) is stored in the column, it won't work any more:

Sample table:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, field varchar2(10));

Table created.
```

Numbers only:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, field) values (1, 123456);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from test where field = 123456;

        ID FIELD
---------- ----------
         1 123456
```

Enter value that contains e.g. letters in `field`:

```
SQL> insert into test (id, field) values (2, 'ABC');

1 row created.


SQL> select * from test where field = 123456;
ERROR:
ORA-01722: invalid number



no rows selected

SQL>
```

---

So, it is not "Apex" to blame, but you who tried to misuse what you have.